# How to prevent Java compile time exceptions in runtime?

Tags: java, maven, runtime-error

From time to time I get exceptions such as `NoSuchMethodError` or `NoClassDefFoundError` in my projects in runtime. Projects are built by `Maven` without any warnings.
Investigations showed that these occurred because I had direct dependency in my project that required different version of a library I also used directly. So dependency tree might look something like this:

- my_project 1.0

  - apache http client 4.2.0
  - cxf 2.6

    - apache http client 4.1.0

or like this:

- my_project 1.0

  - apache http client 4.2.0

    - apache commons codec 1.9
  - struts 2.3

    - apache commons codec 1.4

I fixed these issues by looking for common compatible denominator of conflicting dependency. But this was only after I'd got error in production.

So the question is how to prevent this type of errors to creep into production builds?

I have some ideas how to solve this:

1. Don't depend directly on library, if you already have transitive version of it. So, in case of dependency tree #1 I'd remove apache http client 4.2.0 and start using apache http client 4.1.0. I'd probably need to change my code to do this, but it seems fine for me. Or I could update CXF to a newer version, that uses apache http client 4.2.0 and remove direct dependency on apache http client 4.2.0 from my pom.xml. Is this case every incompatible change CXF team makes in relation to apache http client, I'll notice: my own code won't compile.
   Don't know how to use this approach with dependency tree #2.
2. Use/extend some static analysis tool to detect missing methods or classes. What bothers me  is that I couldn't find tools doing exactly this kind of work. It leads to conclusion that my problem has some other solution. Otherwise somebody would've created such a tool.
3. Completely change my approach to builds. Build everything (all required libraries and my own project) from sources. Compiler will take care of checking for missing methods and classes.
4. Write tests. Seems like a good approach. But it's hard to predict what flows should be tested (e.g. in production remote server could respond with some encoding scheme that I was unaware of) and testing all flows seems impractical, because basically you are rewriting library's tests.

None of those approaches seem complete for me. What approach do you use? How do you solve this problem?

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'compile time exception' in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exclusion tag inside your dependency like this:

```
<exclusions>
     <exclusion>
          <artifactId></artifactId>
          <groupId></groupId>
     </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

take a look at this link -> [link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

and then at the **How to use dependency exclusions** part ~

Comment: it will prohibit a nested dependency of a dependency to be included when it declares inside pom.xml ~ try to read about it using the link I mentioned above ~

Comment: Yes, dependency exclusion is a solution if you know, that you have a conflict and you know proper version of conflicting library. My questions is more about how to find out you have a conflict and find out version of conflicting library satisfying all others. For example, if I add new third-party library with deep dependency tree, how do I detect there's a clash. And how do I choose version for two third-party libraries, that depend on a common third one?

Comment: @dan: There is no universal solution to that final problem, unfortunately.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Agree, it's impossible to resolve conflict automatically. But it seems that detection is possible. Because it's strange to get compile time errors after you've successfully built project.

Comment: @dan: Well, it's a runtime error.  And it's probably due to a class that was available in the version of the library at compile-time, but not in the version of the library that ended up on the classpath at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Maven Enforcer](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) Plugin. This may be overly cautious, but worth a try.